# Best mode to export a Mathematica notebook to LaTeX

Tags: export, latex

I prepared a notebook with Mathematica containing many graphics and I tried to Save As -> LaTeX Document. Once opened in LaTeX I lost every graphic, I can't see the numbered items I inserted, the input and output cells are missing. What is the best way to export an entire notebook to LaTeX? Must I instead copy and paste every single input and output cell? How can I preserve the graphics?

Comment: It's a little clunky but you can save as .pdf and convert to LaTeX

Comment: how can I convert a pdf file in LaTeX?

Comment: There's a [good post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/how-to-convert-pdf-to-latex) with options, the formatting won't be great and I think it will only read the text but it's a start I guess, good luck!